# File name not defined

Tags: python, function

the filename is not defined in python def function. What am I doing wrong?

```
def transform(dataset):
    datause = dataset.copy()
    return datause
datause.head(10)
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1786282cca87> in <module>()
----> 1 datause.head(10)

NameError: name 'datause' is not defined
```

Comment: your func `transform` didnot call

Comment: The name `datause` is only available inside the namespace of the function `transform`.

Comment: How do I go by it? I am a novice in python.

Comment: Is this the entirety of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your `transform` function to get the return result first

```
def transform(dataset):
    datause = dataset.copy()
    return datause

result = transform(yourDataset)
print "result = {}".format(result)
if result:
    result.head(10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Donald. Your suggestion has helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a file. It's an undefined variable. It's undefined because you didn't define it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not properly formatted. What are you trying to accomplish?

Maybe you want something as follows. Be cautious of the `indentation` and/or the need to use `;`, as well as the need to separate the components of a tuple with `,`. However, even the corrected code I put below does not make much programming sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

```
def transform(dataset): 
    datause = dataset.copy(); 
    return (datause, datause.head(10))
```